# Changing ConnectionString authorization method cause migration fail

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I've created project to read from MSSQL DB and display some data. VS's wizards created connection string like the following:

```
<add name="SomeContext" connectionString="data source=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx\_name,port;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework"  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

When I tried to deploy application to the real web server I changed connection string to use faceless DB account:

```
<add name="SomeContext" connectionString="data source=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx\_name,port;User Id=userid;Password=password; MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

It looks like EF thinks that there some migration needed and tries to execute a lot of meaningless operations including attempts to execute SQL expressions with schema creating.

I have no write permissions on this DB server and I don't see any reasons to allow EF change DB structure.

So I'm completely lost there. What is the proper way to change authorization methods without changing on DB side?

Comment: Do you have migrations (manual or automatic) enabled?

Comment: I've tried to enable automigration when I met the trouble. Situation didn't changed. Anyhow I don't know what I need to do. I don't want any migrations.

Comment: Does the database created already ? Or the database doesn't exist, and it needs to be created ?

Answer (score 1):

Try to change connection string to production in VS project, then use Update-Database via Package Manager Console.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty strange for me but the root of the issue was in default "initial catalog". It was stored somewhere for connection with integrated security but when I changed authorization method default was broken. As soon I defined initial catalog it was fixed.